# You are importing a file ending in .less that cannot be found

Tags: c#, dotless

I am trying to compile my `.less` files into a css during runtime. But the `dotless` library is failing to find the `@import file.less` files.

All my files are in the same directory as the main less file.

This is my C# code:

```
    var config = new DotlessConfiguration() {
         MinifyOutput = true,
         ImportAllFilesAsLess = true
    };
    string css = Less.Parse(less,config);
```

The main less file that i am trying to convert:

```
@import "font-awesome.less";
@fa-font-path: "/fonts";

@sco_green: #63b02e;
@sco_orange: #f18500;

@blue-deep:#00a2d1;

@white: #ffffff;
@active: #ffcb8b;
@gray: #999;
@gray-dark: #525252;
@gray-middle: #b8bcba;
@gray-light: #dbdbdb;
@gray-lighter: #efefef;
@gray-super-light: #f7f7f7;
@gray20:#333;
@gray94:#F0F0F0;
```

Web Config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
</configSections>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
    </handlers>

</system.webServer>
<dotless minifyCss="true" cache="true" web="false" disableParameters="true" />
```

Error Message:

[image]

How can i get it to work?

Comment: show real code otherwise its hard to guess.

Comment: I added the .less file contents. What other code should i provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through almost every single search result on google, i found
[this:](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/issues/114)

Basically i need to set current working directory for `dotless` to be able to find @import files:

so all i had to do in C# was:

```
    string filePath = $"{_filePath}\\main.less";
    string less = ReadFile(filePath);
    var dotlessConfig = new dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfiguration();
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(_filePath);
    string css = Less.Parse(less,dotlessConfig);
```

Comment: The dotless LessEngine now has a CurrentDirectory property that you can set, so you can set it just for the engine rather than having to set the current directory for your environment.